# Refereshing window

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have a window with a grid and periodically I need to turn whole screen black.

In order to do that I set grid visibility to hidden:

```
mainGrid.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
```

then, after one second, I change it back to `Visible`.

But after setting visibility to hidden, screen doesn't change at all.

I tried `UpdateLayout`, `InvalidateArrange`, nithing worked...

How to get the grid to hide and reappear again?

Whole code:

```
mainGrid.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
mainGrid.UpdateLayout();
Thread.Sleep(1000);
mainGrid.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
mainGrid.UpdateLayout();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is caused by you telling the UI thread to sleep - no updates will happen in this time. If you need a delay that won't block updates to the screen, use a `DispatcherTimer` or `await Task.Delay()`.

Comment: thats more a comment than an answer consdering this questiones has a million answers aleready

Comment: @DenisSchaf As long as this answers to OP's question, it is an answer (not a comment).